# Writing off exercised options from defunct startup

Tags: taxes, employee-stock-options

4 years ago (2019) I exercised some vested stock options of the startup I worked for. Last year this startup closed shop, and I learned about it now.

Is there any way I can claim as losses for 2022 the cost basis of my options exercising ($3,000) even though the startup officially shut down in November 2021?

This was always a private company and never had a liquidation event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to speak to a tax professional, but according to [IRS Pub. 550](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p550),

> If you do not claim a loss for a worthless security on your original return for the year it becomes worthless, you can file a claim for a credit or refund due to the loss. You must use Form 1040-X, Amended U.S. Individual Income Tax Return, to amend your return for the year the security became worthless. You must file it within 7 years from the date your original return for that year had to be filed, or 2 years from the date you paid the tax, whichever is later.

Since your loss was in 2021, you'll file an amended return to report the loss on [Form 8949 (Sales and Other Dispositions of Capital Assets)](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-form-8949). The loss is recorded as of the end of the tax year, even if the shares became worthless earlier in the year.

Notes:

- If you had nonqualified stock options (NSOs), your cost basis is the FMV when you exercised or your exercise price, whichever is lower.
- If you had incentive stock options (ISOs), your cost basis for capital gains/(losses) is your exercise price, and your AMT cost basis (if different) is the FMV when you exercised or your exercise price, whichever is lower.
- If you had ISOs, it will be a qualifying disposition (the sale is completed more than 2 years from grant and 1 year from exercise) unless your grant date was December 31, 2019, and you early exercised on that day. Since you exercised in 2019 and the stock became worthless on December 31, 2021, a December 31, 2019 grant date is the only way to fall short of the "more than 2 years from grant" requirement. This is extremely unlikely, but if this is the case, your tax impact may be different from the above.